# Missing authorization header in postman response

Tags: wordpress, postman

I am experiencing this error when sending a get request in postman
https://mysite/wp-json/wp/v2/users/me with authorization basic Auth

{
"status": "error",
"error": "MISSING_AUTHORIZATION_HEADER",
"code": "401",
"error_description": "Authorization header not received. Either authorization header was not sent or it was removed by your server due to security reasons."
}

Any body got a solution for this error , would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:

As stated in the plugin documentation it could be that the header are disabled, you can enabled them via .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
```

OLD ANSWER:

It is telling you to send basic authentication header, you can do that using postman inside the "Authorization" tab and selecting type -> Basic Auth. Two fields will appear for username + password so that you can paste your credential there and use the route.

Another option would be to use this plugin: https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/ (or something similar).

In order to be logged in you need to get a "token" first, which then you have to send via postman inserting it in the authorization panel, choosing type -> Bearer token and pasting it there.

If you are using the plugin i've pasted you have to make a POST to this route: /WP-JSON/JWT-AUTH/V1/TOKEN sending

```
 $http.post( apiHost + '/jwt-auth/v1/token', {
    username: 'admin',
    password: 'password'
  } )
```

So to make it clear again:

1. Authenticate yourself using the REST route /WP-JSON/JWT-AUTH/V1/TOKEN
2. Get the token from that request
3. Use it as Authorization -> Bearer token on postman
4. Enjoy :D

Comment: I am sending the basic Auth like you said , but I am getting the same response . I don't want to use the JWT token because I want all the users to login using the username and password

Comment: I updated my answer, try that again